# Length of method in Java affects performance

Tags: java, performance, methods

Many coding standards prescribe an exact length around method length in a class in Java which is around 20-30 lnes. Does the method length i.e number of lines inside the same affect performance is its beyond a certain number OR is it just for readability and modularity ? Should we divide a logical method of 100 lines to two different methods of 50 lines each just to conform to a standard  which says method length is 50 lines ?

Comment: Bytecode matters. not your source code!

Answer (score 4):

This is not about performance, but about readability and modularity. Shorter methods are:

- easier to read -- you don't need to scroll up and
  down to understand complicated execution logic, method name will tell you what is going on here;
- easier to maintain -- if signature or behavior of one small method is changed, you need to rewrite only those unit tests that are related to this particular method.

Answer (score 1):

**Many coding standards prescribe an exact length around method length in a class in Java?** 
Some coding standards prescribe method length,and most of the time they prescribe a smaller length anywhere from 5-10 lines the purpose is to write smaller easily understandable self documented code.

**Does the method length i.e number of lines inside the same affect performance?**
Number of lines inside the function doesn't affect the performance.

This is an old belief in the early days of computing having more number of functions caused a performance issue which is called as function call overhead,this is no more an issue in 21st century. The modern java compilers are much more sophisticated for ex: memory allocation in java is much faster than that of C.
So you need not to worry about the performance and can focus on writing well understandable code

Answer (score 0):

The performance decrease is neglible. But for the sake of maintaining your code you should try to keep your methods as small as possible and stick to a function. For example, if your method is `addStringToArray` you shouldn't be doing anything other than adding a string to the array. Also if you have a long method and you decide to split it up, realize that this also increases the amount of calls the JVM has to make.